# How to set boolean values in an INI configuration file?

Tags: app-config, ini

I've seen a variety of ways used to set boolean values in INI files:

- `variable = true`
- `variable = 1`
- `variable = on`
- `variable = yes`

Which is the most canonical, common, and/or preferred way?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's no spec for INI files, but for whatever it's worth, I'll list the behaviour of a few implementations from languages I know.

Python's built-in `configparser` module offers a [`getboolean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.getboolean) that behaves as follows:

> the accepted values ... are `'1'`, `'yes'`, `'true'`, and `'on'`, which cause this method to return `True`, and `'0'`, `'no'`, `'false'`, and `'off'`, which cause it to return `False`.

In PHP's [`parse_init_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php), on the other hand:

> String values *"true"*, *"on"* and *"yes"* are converted to **TRUE**. *"false"*, *"off"*, *"no"* and *"none"* are considered **FALSE**.

Meanwhile, .NET has no built-in support for INI parsing, but its most popular INI-parsing library, [ini-parser](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser), offers no support whatsoever for automatic parsing of values and returns them all as strings. Its [*Getting Started*](https://github.com/rickyah/ini-parser#getting-started) examples show parsing booleans with .NET's [`Boolean.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.parse), which will accept the strings `"true"` and `"false"` (with any capitalisation) and throw an exception if given anything else.

In summary: there is absolutely no consistency on this question between different implementations of INI parsers.

I would recommend:

- If you are only going to parse your INI using a single parser, check how that parser behaves and craft your INI to suit its particular implementation.
- If you need to support a wide range of parsers (for example, for language interoperability), then either abandon INI as a format entirely, or else entirely avoid using any of the magic boolean values that some parsers understand and instead stick to `1` and `0`.

Comment: Ironically, I just discovered Delphi's implementation expects `1`/`0` - I'm a bit surprised `true`/`True`/`false`/`False` don't work. Neither does `yes`/`no`. Seems problematic, if you want apps written in different languages to share the same INI file...

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the parser of the ini file.
The values are always strings.

**true/false** : In C# I can convert true and false strings directly to bool. Equals readability and easy conversion. less code.

**0/1** : I have to convert string 0 and 1 to int before converting to bool. Smaller ini file size. Less readable. more code.

**yes/no and on/off** I would have to use a if/switch statement. readable. more code.

**My preferred way is true/false.** Object serialize to true/false, you can use true/false with the sql bit type even though it stores as 0/1. So the only down side would be size which can be minor in most contexts.